Are all sets that are not Lebesgue-measurable neither open nor closed?
I have a question regarding Lebesgue non-measurable sets.  From my reading, I understand that the following is true:

The Borel $\sigma$-field on a topological space (I am assuming that there is only one per topological space) contains all open and closed sets in that space.

The Borel sets contained in the Borel $\sigma$-field of a topological space are a subset of (i.e. contained in) the collection of Lebesgue-measurable sets in that space.


From this (assuming the two points I stated above are correct), I concluded that the only non-measurable sets must all be neither open nor closed.  Is this correct?
My apologies in advance if I inadvertently broke any rules of this site in asking this question.

All correct, yes.

This question is probably a poor fit for this site, though.

@CaM, Thank you for your response - how do I give you an upvote?

No need to upvote a simple comment! ^_^
